# Multiplying rem units by a value to output deg units

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, css-variables, css-calc

```css
:root {
  --length: 10rem;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: calc( var( --length ) / 5 ); /*dividing by a unitless number works*/
  width: var( --length );
  height: var( --length );
  background-color: #444;
}

/* issue in question below */
hr {
  transform: rotate( 
    calc( 
      var( --length ) * 4.5deg 
    ) 
  );
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Multiplying `var( --length )` which equals `10rem` by `4.5` to get 45 is the desired result of the `calc()` function. The primary problem is getting the result of the `calc()` function to register in degrees.

Essentially I'm multiplying `10rem` by `4.5deg` with a desired output of `45deg`.

Attempts have been made using a unitless value for 4.5 instead of `4.5deg` and tacking on `deg` at the end of or after the `calc()` function. This did not work.

**This question is primarily academic in that it has to do with the limits of vanilla CSS itself. Answers involving preprocessors such as SASS are beyond the scope.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unitless value for the length instead then you can put back the `rem` unit easily for the other values

```css
:root {
  --length: 10;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: calc( var( --length ) * 1rem / 5 );
  width: calc(var( --length ) * 1rem);
  height: calc(var( --length ) * 1rem);
  background-color: #444;
}

/* issue in question below */
hr {
  transform: rotate( 
    calc( 
      var( --length ) * 4.5deg 
    ) 
  );
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: You're good ^^. It seems like best practice then would be to define all CSS variables without units if I'm anticipating lots of calculations. Brilliant.

Comment: @devsandbox yes exactly, keep the units at the end ;)